# Separating token authentication as a separate project

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-identity, nancy, json-web-token

I want to decouple my authorization logic as a separate project. However, it seems that the token generated is not valid for the whole solution. How do I make a nancy token along with its claims valid/verifiable for the whole solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why would an auth token not be valid for a particular library? It shouldn't make any difference whatsoever

Comment: The project that generates the token is separate from the project that contains the api controllers. When I try to validate the token, it fails. Maybe I am doing something wrong